# Create closed areas from open areas

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

I should convert mono-colored seamless pattern to colored one. The problem is -instead of masking, the shapes were cut at the perimeter and expanded, thus using live paint is impossible.

I look for a simple way to "re"-create an area enclosed by cut edges, i.e. connect 2 points to "close" the area and to color it.

For example, I have this cut shape -

[image]

Which is expanded, so there is no "area" to fill -

[image]

I need to fill the cut open areas with colors - the apexes are pointing to the areas to fill. Grey color is Ai background.

[image]

How can achieve that with minimal efforts instead of recreating and masking the whole pattern?

UPD if it unclear, I moved the object to the right to show that the areas of interest are open spaces, not enclosed areas or objects bounds -

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Live Paint Bucket Tool**.

- Select the art
- Grab the **Live Paint Bucket Tool**
- Click once to create the Live Paint Group
- Pick a color
- Click the areas to fill them with color

To get back to standard objects, simply click the `Expand` button on the **Control Bar**

### Edit:

I missed that the left side was the artboard, not a grey object.

For hollow objects, just draw a rectangle on the left side.... use the Live Paint Bucket... expand.. delete the rectangle.

You could also draw a rectangle behind the shapes and use `Pathfinder > Trim`. Then delete any unwanted pieces.

Comment: the areas I want to fell are areas without any objects... I should recreate them. Did I explained that unclear? :( Or your answer address the question??

Comment: please look on the update

Comment: @Ilan see updated answer :)

Comment: if I create a rectangle equivalent in size to the pattern size - will it work?

Comment: I don't understand -- [View this Gif](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sHqMQ.gif) If it's a pattern swatch, double click the swatch in the **Swatches Panel** and edit the pattern there.

Comment: that worked - I've created a rectangle around the whole pattern and LivePainted the spaces. :0